# Counting the special character and character in an array and giving the sum of the numbers in an array

Tags: python, arrays, special-characters

```
ar=input("Enter the elements:").split()
sum=0
cr=0

for i in range(len(ar)):
    if(not ar[i].isalpha()):
        a=int(ar[i])
        sum=sum+a
    else:
         cr=cr+1
print("Sum of the elements is :",sum)
print(" No of Characters in the array:",cr)
```

I can count the character but idk what to do for special characters

To count the Special charcter and give the sum

Comment: Can you share example input and expected output. Can you explain what you mean by "Special Characters"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if it's neither `alpha` niether `numeric`:

```
ar=input("Enter the elements:")
char_count = 0
special_char_count = 0

for char in ar:
    if char.isalpha():
        char_count += 1
        continue
    
    if not char.isnumeric():
        special_char_count += 1
    
print("Sum of alpha: ", char_count)
print("Sum of special charachters: ", special_char_count)

# Input: abc&--
# Output: Sum of alphabet:  3
#         Sum of special charachters:  3
```

Comment: Sum of special characters becomes 3 in `abc&--`

Comment: Thnaks thus helped a lot